# How to use same cookie when call API?

Tags: javascript, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have aplication by .Net Core API 7 and my app will save user info by session like this code  when they login

```
  public int _UserId
        {
            get
            {

                if (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId") == null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", 0);
                }

                return (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId");

            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", value);
            }
        }
```

When the user calls other api, my program will auto get session and work with this. When I use Postman and Swagger Ui it work well.

The problem is when I call api by js, it is not in the same *cookie*(I really don't know what to call it ). In this below code, I call login API and this success, my program will save session. Then I call api `GetCurrentUser` to get session which I have been saved before and I can't get result because **two functions I call are not in the same** **cookie**

```
    async function callApiLogin(username, password) {
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = "http://localhost:5296/api/Account/Login";
        xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        xhttp.onload = function () {
            if (xhttp.status === 200) {
                const response = xhttp.responseText;
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                // Handle error
            }
        };

        const data = {
            username: username,
            password: password,
        };

        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    callApiLogin("string1", "string");
    console.log("Login completed");
    setTimeout(() => {
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = "http://localhost:5296/api/User/GetCurrentUser"; // Replace with the actual API endpoint

        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        xhttp.onload = function () {
            if (xhttp.status === 200) {
                const response = xhttp.responseText;
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                // Handle error
            }
        };

        xhttp.send();
    }, 5000);
```

How can I call API by js in the same cookie like Swagger and Postman?

Should I use JWT token instead of sessions?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, XML Request won't automatically include cookie. Try something like this:[image]

Comment: Please add your code as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea.

Comment: I can't allow credential in my .net core code. I try somthing like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#enable-cors. But it not work

Comment: Oh, I do it by my self. Just use ```app.UseCors(x => x
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                 .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                                                     //.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44351")); // Allow only this origin can also have multiple origins separated with comma
                 .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials```
Althought, I use `xhttp.withCredentials = true`. The backend code still not return my session that I have been saved when I use api login

Answer (score 0):

When making requests from JavaScript, you need to ensure that you include cookies in your requests. You can do this using the fetch API or Axios. Here's an example using fetch.

```
const loginData = {
username: "your_username",
password: "your_password"
};

// Perform a login request
fetch('http://localhost:5296/api/Account/Login', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify(loginData),
credentials: 'include', // Include credentials (cookies)
})
.then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        // Successfully logged in
        // You can make other authenticated requests here
    } else {
        // Handle login error
    }
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: you need to add cookie authentication to your backend service, and you also need to add CORS policy and enable allowcredentials to ensure cookies are not constrained.

Comment: I can't allow credential in my .net core code. I try somthing like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#enable-cors. But it not work

Comment: Oh, I do it by my self. Just use ```app.UseCors(x => x
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                 .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                                                     //.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44351")); // Allow only this origin can also have multiple origins separated with comma
                 .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials```
Althought, I use xhttp.withCredentials = true. The backend code still not return my session that I have been saved when I use api login